# Is Blender appropriate for making high quality and detailed architectural models. If no then please suggest alternatives

Tags: edit-mode

I am an aspiring civil engineer and thinking to make some structural models and even tried to make some but Blender is not upto my expectations, are there any alternatives ?

Comment: Have you enabled any of the architecture add ons such as Archimesh and Archipack? I suspect CAD programs such as  LibreCAD may be more suitable.

Comment: I'll try them out and thanks for the suggestion !